# Примеры применения шаблона Singleton в нескольких потоках

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

Чтобы исключить создание более одного экзэмпляра класса, который реализует шаблон Singleton, при использовании нескольких потоков, необходимо сделать класс потокобезопасным. Для этого есть несколько способов со своими плюсами и имнусами.

Какие есть реальные примеры, когда может понадобиться использовать "одиночку" в нескольких потоках?

Comment: Да нету необходимости использовать синглтон. Вообще. Это не паттерн, это антипаттерн.

Comment: @Etki не используйте.

Comment: Когда вы используете его в веб-приложении. Каждый запрос от client-side обрабатывается отдельным потоком.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё пример с коннектом на сервере.

1. Получаем коннект. Запоминаем время коннекта
2. Получаем данные. Проверяем, не прошло ли время коннекта
3. Если время коннекта прошло, или возникла ошибка коннекта - идем в п.1 иначе п.2.

Все завернуто так, чтобы только один поток пытался получить коннект, а другие пока что ждали.
**P.S.:** Пример может и не удачный, но я такое встречал и в некоторых ситуациях это оправдано(к примеру я видел такое при использовании коннекта к `hbase`)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, данный патерн используют, если создание объекта довольно дорогая операция, занимает много времени и/или много памяти. Такой объект должен быть `thread-safe`. Из примеров, могу привести класс `java.lang.Runtime` содержащий информацию о рабочем окружении в котором запущена `jvm`.

Answer (score -2):

Расскажу на своем примере. я работаю с большими данными из БД. мне нужно один раз получить эти все данные, потом юзать их в разных местах кода. 
В тестах некоторые проверки запускаются параллельно, если не буду использовать синглтон, то придется передавать объект. Натыкаешься на проблемы, если объект передаешь по ссылке на 2 и выше уровня: ссылка на объект бьется (это касается java, в с++ и С# по умолчанию копия передается). Делать мне копию объекта слишком затратно по памяти, поэтому спасает синглтон. И все работает великолепно.

Comment: *натыкаешься на проблемы, что если объект передаешь на 2 и выше уровня, то ссылка бьется* - господи, ЧТО?

Comment: @Etki бывает. ты сам все прекрасно понял о чем я ;-)

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, было бы неплохо, чтобы все пользователи поняли.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator вообще ни разу не понял